Great Expectations: UserConfigurableProfiler: MetricResolutionError:
I have this code. When I do not use profiler, everything is fine on my code but when I use the profiler lines in my code, the code could not finish itself and it is not giving definitive error as well, just notebook is frozen and MetricResolutionError. What is the wrong. I am completely following the documnetation: "https://medium.com/@Sasakky/how-to-use-great-expectations-with-bigquery-54aad4aa2dd" and GX Documentation.
from jsonschema import validate as validate_json

from typing import Dict, Any, Tuple
import pandas as pd

import great_expectations as gx
from great_expectations.checkpoint import Checkpoint
from great_expectations.profile.user_configurable_profiler import UserConfigurableProfiler  

from dq_suite.input_validator import validate_dqrules
from dq_suite.output_transformations import extract_dq_validatie_data, extract_dq_afwijking_data, create_brontabel, create_bronattribute, create_dqRegel

def df_check(dfs: list, dq_rules: str, check_name: str) -> Tuple[Dict[str, Any], Dict[str, Tuple[Any, Any]], pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
    """
    Function takes DataFrame instances with specified Data Quality rules. 
    and returns a JSON string with the DQ results with different dataframes in results dict, 
    and returns different dfs as specified using Data Quality rules
    
    :param dfs: A list of DataFrame instances to process.
    :type dfs: list[DataFrame]
    :param dq_rules: JSON string containing the Data Quality rules to be evaluated.
    :type dq_rules: str
    :param check_name: Name of the run for reference purposes.
    :type check_name: str
    :return: A dictionary of Data Quality results for each DataFrame, 
             along with metadata DataFrames:  brontabel_df, bronattribute_df, dqRegel_df .
             Results contains 'result_dqValidatie' and 'result_dqAfwijking'.
    :rtype: Tuple[Dict[str, Any], pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]
    """
    results = {}
    name = check_name
    validate_dqrules(dq_rules)
    rule_json = json.loads(dq_rules)
    brontabel_df = create_brontabel(rule_json)
    bronattribute_df = create_bronattribute(rule_json)
    dqRegel_df = create_dqRegel(rule_json)
    for df in dfs:
       
        context_root_dir = "/dbfs/great_expectations/"
        context = gx.get_context(context_root_dir=context_root_dir)
 
        dataframe_datasource = context.sources.add_or_update_spark(name="my_spark_in_memory_datasource_" + name)
 
        df_asset = dataframe_datasource.add_dataframe_asset(name=name, dataframe=df)
        batch_request = df_asset.build_batch_request()
 
        expectation_suite_name = name + "_exp_suite"
        context.add_or_update_expectation_suite(expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name)
 
        validator = context.get_validator(batch_request=batch_request, expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name)

        #Profiler
        profiler = UserConfigurableProfiler(profile_dataset=validator)
        suite = profiler.build_suite()
        # print("SUITE: ")
        # print(suite)

        # to compare table_name in dq_rules and given table_names by data teams
        matching_rules = [rule for rule in rule_json["tables"] if rule["table_name"] == df.table_name]
 
        if not matching_rules:
            continue
 
        for rule in matching_rules:
            df_name = rule["table_name"]
            unique_identifier = rule["unique_identifier"]
            for rule_param in rule["rules"]:
                check = getattr(validator, rule_param["rule_name"])
                for param_set in rule_param["parameters"]:
                    kwargs = {}
                    for param in param_set.keys():
                        kwargs[param] = param_set[param]
                    check(**kwargs)
 
            validator.save_expectation_suite(discard_failed_expectations=False)
 
            my_checkpoint_name = name + "_checkpoint"
 
            checkpoint = Checkpoint(
                name=my_checkpoint_name,
                run_name_template="%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-" + name + "-template",
                data_context=context,
                batch_request=batch_request,
                expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name,
                action_list=[
                    {
                        "name": "store_validation_result",
                        "action": {"class_name": "StoreValidationResultAction"},
                    },
                ]
            )
 
            context.add_or_update_checkpoint(checkpoint=checkpoint)
            checkpoint_result = checkpoint.run()
            output = checkpoint_result["run_results"]
            print(f"{df_name} output: ", output)
            for key, value in output.items():
                result = value["validation_result"]
                result_dqValidatie = extract_dq_validatie_data(name, result)
                result_dqAfwijking = extract_dq_afwijking_data(name, result, df, unique_identifier)
                results[df_name] = (result_dqValidatie, result_dqAfwijking)
      
    return  results ,brontabel_df, bronattribute_df, dqRegel_df , suite

